# Python command print() does not print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to debug a script inserting print() commands to see the states of variables. But those commands don't seem to work. When I debug line by line using PyScripter it just skips those lines. I'm using Python 3. The problem is in a method of a class defined in a .py file, called from another .py file. I insert part of the code below.

```
class BaseGen:
    def duracion(self, rangos, anio, semanas, verificar_ver_py=True):
        print('some string')
```

The calling line is:

```
duracion = base.duracion(rangos_parte, anio, semanas)
```

Comment: you haven't defined `string` anywhere. Maybe you are passing the wrong variable to print.

Comment: You should get an error because you haven't defined `string`

Comment: It is, I just didn't include the definition in the question. I'll edit the question to something more helpfull.

Comment: Does it simply print nothing or is there some kind of error being thrown? SO can help you better if you post the response from Python. If it didn't run entirely, check if you called it correctly or if some flow control made it skip that block of code

Comment: @José, sorry, didn't see that :) edited mine as well

Comment: It prints nothing. An unrelated error comes after that (the one I'm tring to debug)

Comment: Try calling the function being skipped over in the Python console and post the result here

Comment: Most operating systems buffer output to stdout until a line break is met. Try changing `print('some string')` to `print('some string\n')`

Comment: @Morten Jensen, on what OS does that make a difference? I've used GNU/Linux and Windows with Python, and it's never made a difference.

Comment: @José Maybe the "unrelated error" isn't that unrelated after all...

Comment: @José, if the "unrelated error" is raised on a line PRIOR to your print function, you need to solve that one first

Comment: What's your original assigment to `base`?

Comment: @BenjiSparks I'm not sure if Python's `print` statement flushes the buffer or adds a linebreak, but `printf` system calls will get buffered on linux and windows.

Comment: I tried the code using the console and it's working. (I can debug the unrelated error now.) It's an issue of PyScripter. Thanks!

Comment: @Morten Jensen, I know for a fact that a line break is added, not sure about the buffer, but I've never had to use "\n" except for formatting reasons

Comment: @José great to hear! Well done :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with PyScripter. I tried the same code on the Python console and it was just fine.